# Calling git in pre-commit hook

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook

I am getting weird results of running my git pre-commit hook, for example when I do 
git diff --name-only in terminal it seems to give different result than 
when it is executed in .git/hooks/pre-commit

So my questions are:

1. Am I allowed to call git inside git hooks?
2. If 1. is ok: when exactly is pre-commit hook called if I do git commit
   -am"bla"? In particular does git do staging first and then it calls the pre-commit hook or not?

I ask this because I tried 2 or 3 times this:
I modify a file, I run the script manually, it prints out

```
#! /bin/sh -xv
files=$(git diff --name-only)
+ git diff --name-only
+ files=path/to/file.h
echo $files
+ echo path/to/file.h
path/to/file.h
...
```

When I do git commit -am"eh" then the output is different

```
#! /bin/sh -xv
files=$(git diff --name-only)
+ git diff --name-only
+ files=
echo $files
+ echo
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. Am I allowed to call git inside git hooks?

Yes, but you must exercise caution, as there are a number of things set in the environment and you're working with something that is in the middle of being done:

- `GIT_DIR` is set to the path to the Git directory.
- `GIT_WORKTREE` may be set to the path to the work-tree (from `git --work-tree`).
- Other Git variables, such as `GIT_NO_REPLACE_OBJECTS`, may be set from the command line as well.

(You should leave these set if you're continuing to work with the current repository, but clear them out if you're working with a *different* repository.)

> 2. If 1. is ok: when exactly is pre-commit hook called if I do git commit -am"bla"? In particular does git do staging first and then it calls the pre-commit hook or not?

This is complicated.

There are three "modes" that `git commit` uses internally.  (There are no promises about this, but that's how things have been implemented for many years now so this three-modes thing seems pretty stable.)  The modes are:

- `git commit` without `-a`, `--include`, `--only`, and/or any command-line-specified file names.  This is the default or normal mode.  The underlying implementation details do not show through.
- `git commit` *with* `-a` or with command-line-specified file names.  This divides into two sub-modes:

  - such a commit with `--include`, or
  - such a commit with `--only`.

  At this point, the underlying implementation shows through.

The underlying implementation details here involve the thing that Git calls, variously, the *index*, the *staging area*, and (rarely now) the *cache*, which is normally implemented as a file named `$GIT_DIR/index` (where `$GIT_DIR` is the environment variable from the note about point 1).  Normally, there is only one of these: *the* index.  It holds the content that you intend to commit.<sup>1</sup>  When you run `git commit`, Git will package up whatever is *in* the index as the next commit.

But, during the operation *of* `git commit`, there may be up to *three* index files.  For the normal `git commit` there's just the one index, and your pre-commit hook can use it and can even update it.  (I advise against updating it, for reasons we'll see in a moment.)

But, if you do a `git commit -a`, or `git commit --include file.ext`, now there are *two* index files.  There's the content that's ready to be committed—the regular index—*and* one *extra* index, which is the original index plus the result of doing a `git add` on `file.ext` or on all files (the equivalent of `git add -u`).  So now there are *two* index files.

In this mode, Git leaves the regular index file *as* the regular index file.  This file is in `$GIT_DIR/index` as usual.  The *second* index file, with the extra added stuff, is in `$GIT_DIR/index.lock` and the environment variable `GIT_INDEX_FILE` is set to hold that path.  If the commit *fails*, Git will remove the `index.lock` file and everything will be as if you had not run `git commit` at all.  If the commit *succeeds*, Git will rename `index.lock` to `index`, releasing the lock and updating *the* (standard, regular) index all in one motion.

Finally, there's the *third* mode, which you get when you run `git commit --only file.ext` for instance.  Here, there are now *three* index files:

- `$GIT_DIR/index`: The standard index, which holds what it usually does.
- `$GIT_DIR/index.lock`: A copy of the standard index to which `file.ext` has been `git add`-ed.
- `$GIT_DIR/indexsuffix`: A copy of the `HEAD` commit<sup>2</sup> to which `file.ext` has been `git add`-ed.

The environment variable `GIT_INDEX_PATH` points to this third index.  If the commit succeeds, Git will rename the `index.lock` file to `index`, so that it become *the* index.  If the commit fails, Git will remove the `index.lock` file, so that the index goes back to the state it had before you started.  (And in either case, Git removes the third index, which has now served its purpose.)

Note that from a pre-commit hook, you can detect whether `git commit` is a standard commit (`GIT_INDEX_FILE` is unset or set to `$GIT_DIR/index`) or one of the two special modes.  In standard mode, if you want to update *the* index, you can do so as usual.  In the two special modes, you can use `git add` to modify the file that `GIT_INDEX_FILE` names, which will modify what goes into the commit; and if you're in the `--include` style commit, this also modifies what will become the standard index on success.  But if you're in the `--only` mode, modifying the proposed commit *doesn't* affect the standard `index`, *nor* the `index.lock` that will *become* the standard index.

To consider a concrete example, suppose the user did:

```
git add file1 file2
```

so that the standard index matches `HEAD` except for `file1` and `file2`.  Then the user runs:

```
git commit --only file3
```

so that the proposed commit is a copy of `HEAD` with `file3` added, *and*, if this commit succeeds, Git will replace the standard index with one in which `file1`, `file2`, and `file3` are all added (but since `file3` will match the new `HEAD` commit, only files 1 and 2 will be *modified* in the new index).

Now suppose your commit hook runs `git add file4` and the process as a whole succeeds (the new commit is made successfully).  The `git add` step will copy the work-tree version of `file4` into the temporary index, so that the commit will have both `file3` *and* `file4` updated.  Then Git will rename the `index.lock` file, so that `file3` will match the new `HEAD` commit.  But `file4` in the `index.lock` was never updated, so it *won't* match the `HEAD` commit.  It will appear to the user that somehow, `file4` got reverted!  A `git status` will show a pending change to it, staged for commit, and `git diff --cached` will show that the difference between `HEAD` and the index is that `file4` has been changed back to match the `file4` in `HEAD~1`.

You *could* have your pre-commit hook test for this mode and refuse to `git add` files when in this mode, to avoid the problem.  (Or, you could even sneakily add `file4` to `index.lock`, with a second `git add` command!)  But it's generally better to have your hook just reject the commit, with advice to the user to do any `git add`s themselves, so that you don't have to know all of these implementation secrets *about* `git commit` in the first place.

---

<sup>1</sup>The index holds some extra information as well: cache data *about* the work-tree.  That's why it's sometimes called the cache.  These extra copies that I describe here are made by copying the original index, so the extra copies also have the same cache data, except if and when they get updated via `git add`.

<sup>2</sup>It's not specified whether Git makes this copy via the internal equivalent of:

```
TMP=$GIT_DIR/index<digits>
cp $GIT_DIR/index $TMP
GIT_INDEX_FILE=$TMP git reset
GIT_INDEX_FILE=$TMP git add file3
```

or some other means (e.g., the internal equivalent of `git read-tree`), but since this particular copy is always just removed at the end of the process, it doesn't matter: any cache information for the work-tree becomes irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, changes seem to be already cached. Use `git diff --cached --name-only` to list files about to be committed.