# How to add and commit a submodule in the parent project without resetting the state of other submodules?

Tags: git

I am trying to write a script that checks out 'master' in all submodules.

Normally, after a clone, all submodules are in a detached state. I want them to be on a branch however. So my script visits each submodule and under certain conditions checks out a branch.

Roughly speaking, that comes down to say

```
git submodule foreach --recursive 'git checkout master'
```

After such a checkout I also try to fast-forward them. The submodule's
HEAD (master) might no longer be equal to the recorded sha1 in the parent project.
If that is the case, the script also does

```
git add path/to/submodule
git commit -m 'Automatic update of submodule'
```

in the parent (immediately following the 'git checkout master; git merge --ff-only' in the submodule).

That is... that would also commit anything that was added to the index already and
I don't want that: I ONLY want to commit this 'add' of path/to/submodule.

I tried to solve this by wrapping the above in a git stash push/pop:

```
git stash save Automatic stash of parent project by update_submodules.sh
git add "$path"
git commit -m "Updating submodule reference to current HEAD of branch $submodule_branch of $name"
git stash pop
```

However, the `git stash` puts all submodules in a detached state again! And the `git stash pop` does NOT restore that :/

How can I achieve what I want?

EDIT

The answer of torek was used in the final `update_submodules.sh` script
[at line 47](https://github.com/CarloWood/cwm4/blob/2964d5dd04ac3a8d250059660f87d66cc7fb1588/scripts/update_submodule.sh#L47).
It should be called [like this](https://github.com/CarloWood/cwm4/blob/eb56c102e2fe49dc5e75217e9f748cd43a7f83d5/templates/autogen.sh#L46).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the otherwise rather specialized `git commit --only`.

What `git commit --only` does is:

1. create a temporary index<sup>1</sup> and read the existing `HEAD` commit into that temporary index, so that `HEAD` and this temporary index match;
2. `git add` the specified arguments to the temporary index;
3. make a commit from the result;
4. arrange that the regular index also has those `git add`-ed by the time `git commit --only` finishes.

So, the new commit—which is now `HEAD`; the commit that *was* `HEAD` is now `HEAD~1` or `HEAD^` (whichever syntax you prefer: both mean the same thing)—is exactly the same as the old one *except* for the files listed after `--only`.  If some stuff was staged, that same stuff is still staged.  Meanwhile the (main) index is also now updated to account for the fact that the `HEAD` commit has new versions of the specified files.

(In this case the "files" are just the gitlinks, or the one gitlink for the one submodule.)

---

<sup>1</sup>It actually creates *two* temporary index files.  For the complete and gory details, see my answer to [Calling git in pre-commit hook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59686461/1256452).

Comment: Wow - I had no idea you could specify a path and/or files with a `git commit` (in which case --only is the default even)! Thanks!